# How can I change and marker/pin icon on custom map using XamarinFormsMaps?

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I need to customized my pins/markers, I already added all the renderers and classes need it but I still don't know how to change the marker and place an image.

I followed the steps from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin#consuming-the-custom-map

My question is in the map implementation

```
CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Label = "Test pin",
            Position = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183)
        };
        map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
        map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

What do I have to add/change to place an image that I already have in the resources as the marker of this pin?

For now it takes only the image named pin.png which I as a pin, but need also sometimes to use a different image

The renderer have this:

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
        {
            var marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
            marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
            marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
            return marker;
        }
```

Selects directly **Resource.Drawable.pin** and maybe it's possible to call this and change it, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/Map/Droid/Resources/layout

Comment: I added those files manually, but the errors are still there.

Comment: did you add them as resources with correct content type?  There is more to it than just adding them to VS.  I suggest you download the sample app and run it to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that

Comment: @Jason I fixed that and updated the question, maybe you can help me

Comment: if you want a different image, add it to Resources and use it's ID instead of Resource.Drawable.pin

Comment: That wouldn't work, because I want to use that one (pin.png) AND another one, so changing one for the other is not an option :/

Comment: then create two custom pin types and swap them out as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I will reply for purposes of futures queries that will coming until here. You can add your image at Assets folder and change:

`BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin)` by `BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromAsset("pin.png")`